# How to prevent Null pointer exception when query result is null in case of Spring Data CRUD repository using Spring WebFlux

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I am using Spring WebFlux to build a sample WebApplication. I am interacting with the postgres database using spring data's non blocking reactive library r2dbc. I am able to fetch the data and return to the user when the query is returning some result. But when the query is for non-existent values in the database (For ex: I donot have the data for the accountid 112 in my database). I am seeing Null Pointer exception.

```
 @Nullable
  @Query("select sum(callrxinboundcount) from account_stats where botname=$1 and starttime > $2 and endtime < $3 ")
  Mono<Long> findSumOfCallReceivedInboundCountByDurationForBotName( String accountId, Long startTime, Long endTime);


java.lang.NullPointerException: data
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/stat/accountid/112/" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.next(FluxHandle.java:234) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlResult.lambda$map$1(PostgresqlResult.java:113) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTakeUntil$TakeUntilPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxTakeUntil.java:77) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.util.FluxDiscardOnCancel$FluxDiscardOnCancelSubscriber.onNext(FluxDiscardOnCancel.java:86) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:793) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.next(FluxCreate.java:718) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$Conversation.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:735) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.emit(ReactorNettyClient.java:986) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:860) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
        at io.r2dbc.postgresql.client.ReactorNettyClient$BackendMessageSubscriber.onNext(ReactorNettyClient.java:767) ~[r2dbc-postgresql-0.8.6.RELEASE.jar:0.8.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:845) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.11.RELEASE.jar:3.3.11.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:256) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:362) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:358) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.13.RELEASE.jar:0.9.13.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) ~[netty-codec-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425) ~[netty-codec-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.53.Final.jar:4.1.53.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

How can I handle this null pointer exception and return zero incase the value does not exist in the db?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query like this.

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(callrxinboundcount, 0)) FROM account_stats WHERE botname=$1 AND starttime > $2 AND endtime < $3
```

That’s one way I can think of.

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: I will check and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove @Nullable
2. You can consider `Mono` is the `Optional` in the Reactive stack.
3. In your controller or exception handler, it is easy to handle the **non-existence** case.

For example,

1. use [switchIfEmpty](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostHandler.java#L40) to return result directly.
2. use a standalone [ExceptionHandler](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-neo4j/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java#L138) to handle the exception.